Flutter application closes without any error when connecting to TCP connection in release mode
I've developed a Flutter application that connects to a TCP server and sends data using the basic dart:io package:
_socket = await Socket.connect(MyConst.remoteHost, MyConst.remotePort);

It works perfectly in debug mode, but the application crashes in release mode.
I'm developing an IoT app that connects to the IoT device's Wi-Fi, but the network doesn't have internet access.
Future<void> connect() async {
    try {
      _socket = await Socket.connect(MyConst.remoteHost, MyConst.remotePort);
      print('Connected to remote host');

      _socket!.listen(
            (data) {
          print('Received data: ${utf8.decode(data)}');
        },
        onError: (error) {
          print('Error: $error');
        },
        onDone: () {
          print('Connection closed');
          _reconnect();
        }
      );

      sendData({'cmd_id': '4016'});
      _startSendingDataPeriodically();

      await setDeviceTime();
      await setDeviceDate();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to connect: $e');
      _reconnect();
    }
  }

This is my connection function.
It works perfectly in debug mode, but the application crashes in release mode.
It also doesn't throw any error in console but closes it.


First we need to configure the android/app/build.gradle file

defaultConfig {
        // ... other default config ...
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            // ... other release configurations ...
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
    


ABIFilters specifies which Application Binary Interfaces (ABIs) your app supports.It ensures that your app includes native libraries for these specific architectures, which is crucial for VLC to work across different device types.
shrinkResources false - Disables resource shrinking, which can sometimes remove resources needed by native libraries.
minifyEnabled false - Disables code obfuscation and minimization, which can interfere with native libraries.
packagingOptions - It resolves conflicts when multiple libraries include the same file. It tells Gradle how to handle duplicate .so files, which can occur with native libraries like VLC.
This allows your app to split the DEX file (which contains the compiled code) into multiple files, overcoming the 65,536 method limit.

These steps were followed by me and it starts working even in release mode.
